# How to share file for anyone Google Drive API using PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I have been trying over and over, but could not reach any result.
the code is generating permission id and I don't know what that means.

Please do help if anyone succeeded in this before, I just want to share file publicly using the google drive api v2.0

```
$fileId = '18mWN0UWX_z-4A1gag85ou0Im-wvKfMZU-tibdVd8nxY';
$userPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    'type' => 'anyone',
    'role' => 'reader',
    'emailAddress' => 'user@example.com'
  ));

  $request = $service->permissions->create(
    $fileId, $userPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
  $batch->add($request, 'user');
  $domainPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission(array(
    'type' => 'domain',
    'role' => 'reader',
    'domain' => 'example.com'
  ));

  $request = $service->permissions->create(
    $fileId, $domainPermission, array('fields' => 'id'));
  $batch->add($request, 'domain');
  $results = $batch->execute();

  foreach ($results as $result) {
    if ($result instanceof Google_Service_Exception) {
      // Handle error
      printf($result);
    } else {
      printf("Permission ID: %s\n", $result->id);
    }
  }
} finally {
  $service->getClient()->setUseBatch(false);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code snippet which was 2 years old.

```
$uplodedOriginalFile = new Google_Service_Drive_DriveFile();
$originallinkdata = file_get_contents($downloadlink['originallink']);
$uploadedfile = $service->files->insert($uplodedOriginalFile, array(
              'data' => $originallinkdata,
              'uploadType' => 'multipart',
            ));

$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
//$newPermission->setValue($value);
$newPermission->setType('anyone');
$newPermission->setRole('reader');
try 
{
    $service->permissions->insert($uploadedfile['id'], $newPermission);
} 
catch (Exception $e) 
{
    print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
}

$publicOriginallink = "https://googledrive.com/host/".$uploadedfile['id'];
```

So you just need the inserted file Id and keep the permssion for anyone as  reader and append the inserted file Id after "https://googledrive.com/host/ [newly inserted file id which is returned by google drive sdk]"

Answer (score 0):

code snippet worked

```
$fileid =$createdFile['id'];
//--insert permission to file in public
$newPermission = new Google_Permission();
$newPermission->setType('anyone');
$newPermission->setRole('reader');
try 
{$service->permissions->insert($fileid, $newPermission);} 
catch (Exception $e){print "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();}
$publicOriginallink = "https://googledrive.com/host/".$fileid;
```

I just made few changes with Jai's code (Google_Permission) to match with my Google APIs Client Library version.

Comment: In newest version it doesn't have any insert function, hmm..