# How to create a public accessible folder in google drive through drive API?

Tags: php, google-drive-api

I am creating a folder in Google Drive to upload images in it, but to access those images without any authentication I want to make folder public at the time of creating it.

But unfortunately I have not found any additional function or argument to use with this API to create a *new public folder with public accessible permission*.

Here is my code for creating a new folder in Drive:

```
$folder = new Google\Service\Drive\DriveFile();
$folder->setName("MyPublicFolder_media");
$folder->setMimeType('application/vnd.google-apps.folder');
$createdFolder = $service->files->create($folder);
$folderId = $createdFolder->getId();
```

Comment: Just set the permissions once you've created it - see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing to get started. It's a separate operation, you can't do it within the Create command.

Comment: Can you provide an example for changing permission of the folder immediate after creating it through API? I've gone through google's documentation but still unable to change permission through api.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/manage-sharing#change_multiple_permissions_with_batch_requests) shared by @ADyson, you can find a sample on how to share the file using the APIs, just change `'type': 'anyone'`.

Also, I found [these sample](https://tutorialspots.com/php-how-to-share-a-file-publicly-using-google-drive-api-3089.html) codes.

**Level: Anyone with the link**

```
$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission->setValue('default');
$newPermission->setType('anyone');
$newPermission->setRole('reader');
$newPermission->setWithLink('true');
 
$permission = $service->permissions->insert('File_ID', $newPermission );
```

**Level: Public on the web – Anyone can find and view**

```
$newPermission = new Google_Service_Drive_Permission();
$newPermission->setValue('default');
$newPermission->setType('anyone');
$newPermission->setRole('reader');
  
$permission = $service->permissions->insert('File_ID', $newPermission );
```

Modified from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912240/)